# How to write elasticsearch plugin to extend /_search endpoint?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-5

I'm using ES 5.1.2 and I want to do some simple authentication key lookup for every /_search request.
I don't find a very detailed plugin development guide on elastic.co, so far the only document I found is this http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2016/10/19/adding-a-new-rest-endpoint-to-elasticsearch-updated-for-ga/, but it is about create another endpoint.

I found search-guard https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard and from source code it feels like I can create my own plugin `extends Plugin implements ActionPlugin`, but then I'm stuck and don't know where to go.

From the source code I know I can add my own `ActionFilter` and add it into action chain in `Plugin`, such that all request go thru `/_search` endpoint will also go thru my `ActionFilter`. But I don't have a complete list of possible action, which might be `indices:data/read/search` (search) or `indices:admin/delete` (delete index). There are too many to use try and error.

Another thing is, in `ActionFilter`, how do I get POST request payload from a `Request` object? When in `/_search` request, I got `SearchRequest`, but it doesn't have http request headers from browser.

== update ==

Found I could use use stack trace to get the invoke history, so for `ActionFilter` the call stack is like

```
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction$RequestFilterChain.proceed(TransportAction.java:171)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:145)
at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:87)
at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.executeLocally(NodeClient.java:75)
at org.elasticsearch.client.node.NodeClient.doExecute(NodeClient.java:64)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:403)
at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.search(AbstractClient.java:530)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestSearchAction.lambda$prepareRequest$0(RestSearchAction.java:83)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.action.search.RestSearchAction$$Lambda$1405/1241306571.accept(Unknown Source)
at org.elasticsearch.rest.BaseRestHandler.handleRequest(BaseRestHandler.java:82)
```

in `RestSearchAction#prepareRequest`, ES use `parseSearchRequest` and convert `RestRequest` data to `SearchRequest`, which means I can't get `RestRequest` in my `ActionFitler`. Should there be another way to pass this data? Because I want to extend an existed `/_search` not add another endpoint, so I think I should not create any more `RestHandler`

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary solution and source code is [here](https://github.com/rayjcwu/dummy-es-auth-plugin).

Long thing short, when implement your plugin as `RestHandler` (usually with new endpoints), you can skip `registerHandler` and do `registerFilter` only. I implement my logic in `RestFilter`. This works because in ElasticSearch [source code](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/v5.1.2/core/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/rest/RestController.java#L188-L206), when `RestController` gets a new request, it will check if you have any `RestFilter`, if you do then it will go through whole chain of filters, then dispatch to a particular handler based on request URI.

In [search guard 5](https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard/blob/es-5.1.2/src/main/java/com/floragunn/searchguard/auth/BackendRegistry.java#L123) there seems to be a way to directly register a `RestFilter` in `RestController` without creating a `RestHandler`, but I don't understand the whole flow so I didn't use it.

My main references:

- http://david.pilato.fr/blog/2016/10/19/adding-a-new-rest-endpoint-to-elasticsearch-updated-for-ga/
- https://github.com/floragunncom/search-guard/tree/es-5.1.2